# ASP.NET MVC - how do I add subsite (ASP.NET) to my application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.MVC site running at `http://mysite.com`. Now, I want to add subapplication to it, as mentioned here: http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/ckeditor (point 2.2). I tried adding new application, but it doesn't let me add new application at `http://mysite.com`, since there is already one defined. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.

The first would be to create the new application in a sub-path of the parent application.  So the app URL would be http://mysite.com/mysubsite.

The alternative would be to have the sub-site listening on a different port (port 81, for example).  The the URL would be http://mysite.com:81.  The catch with this solution is that users would need to know the port your site is listening on, or only be able to get to it by following a link.

Comment: Okay... But now it gives me this error: `There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined`, so that means that this application still relays on main app, can I make it standalone?

Comment: That would be because the subsite's web.config inherits the settings from the parent application's web.config. Strip out all the settings in the subsite leaving only those that are not present in the parent config file.